# Remove selected area from picture PILLOW

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

```
import numpy
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

im = Image.open("image.jpg").convert("RGBA")

imArray = numpy.asarray(im)

polygon = [(700,150),(1200,150),(1200,450),(1000,650),(700,650)]
maskIm = Image.new('L', (imArray.shape[1], imArray.shape[0]), 0)
ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(polygon, outline=1, fill=1)
mask = numpy.array(maskIm)

newImArray = numpy.empty(imArray.shape,dtype='uint8')

newImArray[:,:,:3] = imArray[:,:,:3]
newImArray[:,:,3] = mask*255

newIm = Image.fromarray(newImArray, "RGBA")
newIm.show()
```

Original Image
[image: Original Image]

After this code, I'm getting this image

[image: this image]

how can I just remove the selection from the picture?

I want to do like this

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to invert your mask - currently, you have 0 around your polygon and 1 inside.

try to change `newImArray[:,:,3] = mask*255` to `newImArray[:,:,3] = (1-mask)*255`